# Read GPIO pin on web page

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, rpi.gpio, php, rpio

I was able to control an led from a web page using the following code. when I call http://myip/pinon.php it will light up the LED and http://myip/pinoff.php will turn off the LED.

pinon.php

```
<?php
          system(“ gpio-g mode 24 out “) ; 
           system(“ gpio-g write 24 1”) ; ?>
```

pinoff.php

```
<?php
          system(“ gpio-g mode 24 out “) ; 
          system(“ gpio-g write 24 0”) ; ?>
```

**Now I want to read input through GPIO pin when I access http://myip/readgpio.php file.**

Is it possible to display a message "button pressed" on the web page(readgpio.php) When a button is pressed or when there is a voltage change on the GPIO pin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just like you are using gpio utility to write to a pin you can use it to read a pin using the command:

```
gpio read <pin>
```

Some documentation and examples [here](http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/).